# Mysql command from bat file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

In a .bat file, I am trying to get the count from a database table and trying to assign it to a variable.
But echo of the variable shows that the variable is getting assigned to the statement string value instead of the count. When I execute only the statement in command prompt I am able to see the count, which means the statement is correct. Need help in assigning this count to a variable.

```
Code Snippet:
SET x='mysql -uroot -pmysql -N testdatabase -e"select count(*) from    test"'
echo "x :" %x%
```

Answer (score 1):

In a batch file it's not that simple I'm afraid. You will need to call this strange `for` syntax:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('mysql -uroot -pmysql -N testdatabase -e"select count(*) from    test"') do @set x=%%a
echo "x :" %x%
```

Or you may try Powershell script file which looks much nicer:

```
$x = & mysql -uroot -pmysql -N testdatabase -e"select count(*) from    test"
"x : $x"
```

Comment: I agree the batch file looks strange, hence I used cygwin utility to execute shell script in my windows machine using your second suggestion and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @DJones I'm glad it worked. If you are happy with the response please mark it as an answer. Thanks